# Error while publishing OpenGraph action "At least one reference object must be specified"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the following error while publishing an action via open graph. I have around 10 actions which are published perfectly. Only this one is giving me the error:

```
code: 100
"At least one reference object must be specified"
```

Here is my publishing code :

```
FB.api(
        '/me/'+fAction,
        'post',
        sObject,
    function(response) 
    {
           if (!response || response.error) 
           {
              for (var prop in response) 
              {
                console.log(response[prop]);
                callbackToFlash(0);
              }
           } else 
           {
              console.log('success'+object);
              callbackToFlash(1);
           }
        }
);
```

The object and action pair exist on my application, I've verified that. After searching on the web seems like it was caused because of a facebook error. Which facebook has marked as closed.

Any ideas on what to do about it?

Comment: Where are you specifying the object URL? Are you sure you're doing it correctly? Does your object type have a property of type 'Object'? If so, does the object you're trying to post validate correctly in [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: It works perfectly fine in the facebook Debug Tool and so do the rest of the object/action pairs

Comment: When i had this error it was caused by an incorrect param I was sending.  I recommend you click on the "Get code" link next to the story in fb dev console and make sure what you send matches whats in there

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var obj = {"og:title": title, "og:image": imgurl,"og:description": des};

        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.likes',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                    object:obj


            })
        }, function (response) {
            // Debug response (optional)
            console.log(response);
        });
```